# Run MPI on SLURM through a shared NFS drive

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, slurm

I've set up an NFS synced drive from my head node (node0), and mounted this drive to my worker nodes (node1...node3). I use this synced drive as a "scratch" for users to run their jobs through SLURM. Additionally, I use it to install shared programs, such as MPICH 3.2, which was compiled and installed through node0.

I've noticed that when running an MPI job through SLURM, the job executes as long as node0 is the host node. If I submit the job to the other nodes (e.g. node2 and node3, where node2 is the host), the job doesn't execute. How can I make it run on other nodes to free up the head node?

EDIT: The ff. is the output of the MPI job if run through SLURM:

```
srun: error: timeout waiting for task launch, started 1 of 2 tasks
srun: Job step 4118.0 aborted before step completely launched.
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: *** STEP 4118.0 ON node2 CANCELLED AT 2018-05-21T20:24:29 ***
srun: error: node2: task 0: Killed
[mpiexec@node2] control_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_cb.c:208): assert (!closed) failed
[mpiexec@node2] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@node2] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:198): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@node2] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:340): process manager
```

Comment: You need to provide way more information. What do you mean by “the job does not execute”?

Comment: Have you tried to execute it without Slurm?

Comment: @siserte yes, I have and directly executing mpiexec on node2 successfully calls out the processors needed, _i.e._ mpiexec -n 8 -hosts node2,node3 ./mpi-hello

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've added the output of the MPI job when run through SLURM

Comment: MPI on node2 is unable to launch MPI environment on the other nodes. Make sure that you can run ssh passwordless from node2 to node3.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov yes, I can ssh passwordless from node2 to node3. still doesn't work though :(